# Is there a way to improve perfomance of preload/eager_load?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, performance

I have a principal model for Customers and another for appointments that have locations and products

Currently I preload the locations and products but the server just explode(timeout).

I need a way to improve the performance for this case.

Example:

`@customers.preload(:locations, :products)`

Do you have any suggestion for this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: index your keys and columns which you are using for searching.

Comment: Preloading is good for toy implementations; it is potentially too costly for large production systems.  We need to see the schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and queries to discuss further.